# How to apply scale animation when uibutton is dragged?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uibutton, drag

I want to apply  scaling animation to  UIButton.When user drag button upside of the screen the scaling is decreased and when drag down to the screen scaling is increase of UIButton.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at CGAffineTransform.  In your dragging code just set the scale based on the y coordinate of your view.